# Unique ID for Google Form that a survey respondent can see

Tags: google-forms

I work for a small NGO that identifies and tracks invasive species. I am trying to solve a issue we have with tracking submitted samples. We have our volunteers and collaborators fill-out and submit a google form and that works fine. However, in order to track any physical samples that are later shipped, we would like to have a unique ID that those volunteers can see and then use when they submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have several alternatives

1. Use the form response timestamp (assuming that is very unlikely that two submissions will be logged with the same timestamp)
2. Use the edit response URL
3. Generate the unique ID in advance and add them to the responses.

Comment: Thank you very much Ruben. I would be happy with using the timestamp method, however how do I make it so that a the participant can see this or the edit response URL? Is there a way to include this in the thank you paragraph they get at the conclusion of the survey or in their follow-up (confirmation) email?

Comment: @Tristan There is no way to include the timestamp or any other calculated value on the form submission confirmation page. You can use the built-in function to send the responses to a spreadsheet and share it with your team or use Google Apps Script to send them a custom email message included the timestamp/edit response url, etc.